# Changing ChecklistBox's CheckBox Background Color

Tags: colors, background, listitem

i am working on checklistBox, wherein, i am filling the checklistBox at runtime from database, now while filling i check, for a condition, if its false than, that ListItem in CheckListBox should be disabled, else it should be enabled, its working properly, but i want to go one step ahead and want to change the background color of the disabled listItem. how to change the ListItem background color of the selected listItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys,
I got the answer for my question..

In the for loop, this statement will change the color of checkBox within checklistBox:

```
checkListBox1.Items[i].Attribites.Add("style","background-color:red");
```