# changing background colors when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a slider button connected to a checkbox like the one found here: http://www.paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css.  The slider works fine, but i can't make it change the background color when it is clicked.

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and found what should be the answer (ex. here: [Change background color of div when checkbox is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889408/change-background-color-of-div-when-checkbox-is-clicked) and [Changing ChecklistBox's CheckBox Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277809/changing-checklistboxs-checkbox-background-color)), but when I try to apply it to my code it doesn't change the background color.

A fix in CSS would be best since all of the design is in CSS already, but Jquery is obviously fine too.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Here's what I've got (sorry in advance for the lengthy in CSS)
html:

```
<div class="checkboxOne">
    <input type="checkbox" 
    value="1" id="checkboxOneInput" name="" />
    <label for="checkboxOneInput"></label>
</div>
```

css:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

.checkboxOne{
width: 220px;
height: 40px;
background-color: yellow;
margin: 20px 60px;
border-radius: 50px;
font-family:Calibri;
position: relative;
}

.checkboxOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
left: 120px;
background:orange;
}

/*slider*/
.checkboxOne label {
display: block;
width: 92px;
height: 22px;
border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease;
-o-transition: all .1s ease;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease;
transition: all .1s ease;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 9px;
z-index: 1;
left: 12px;
background:green;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I need to clarify, I need to change the (yellow) background of the the checkbox to a new color.

Comment: another comment...changing 'body' to 'div' was sufficient.  Thanks Vucko!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **JQuery** with *click event* on `label`(changing the `body` element):

```
$('label').on('click',function(){
    var color=$(this).css('background-color');
    if(color == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') { //green
        $('body').css('background-color','red');
    }
    else{
        $('body').css('background-color','blue');
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNZcG/).